# Updating html content on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple webpage containing comments in a table. I can successfully populate it by calling following function on "window.onload" event.

```
function FillCommentsTable() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var comments = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var i = 0;
      var old_tbody = document.getElementById("comments");
      var new_tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
      for (i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        var row = new_tbody.insertRow(-1);
        var id = row.insertCell(0);
        var user = row.insertCell(1);
        var comment = row.insertCell(2);
        var timestamp = row.insertCell(3);
        id.innerHTML = comments[i].Id;
        user.innerHTML = comments[i].User;
        comment.innerHTML = comments[i].Comment;
        timestamp.innerHTML = comments[i].Timestamp;
      }
      old_tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(new_tbody, old_tbody);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "API/get_comments.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The webpage also have functionality to submit and delete comment with simple form calling the API that manipulates the database storing the comments. The wanted functionality here is that after the submit/delete form has been submitted and called the API the page is reloaded and the table updated. To achieve this I have tried to reload the page on submit with:

```
<form action="API/delete_comment.php" method="post"
onsubmit="window.location.reload()">
  <input type="number" name="id">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

but this seems to have no effect except that the expected call to the API is sent. This also only occurs when trying to update the table with a form since just binding a button:

```
<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Load comments</button>
```

works as intented and updates the table correctly. Is it not possible to sent both the GET for the webpage and the POST to the API triggered on the same event or what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to call the reload as the last thing in your `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)` block?

Comment: Is there any other code bound to the onsubmit event of this form? By default a posted form should redirect to the action.

Comment: @Illdapt I think that would trigger a recursive loop while I have the same function bound to the onload event.

Comment: @Reinard No the only code bound to onsubmit is the reload. The API however returns 204 No content which to my understanding stops the redirect.

Comment: @Highhand - Glad my answer helped you.. I would also suggest giving the id field a unique id attribute because "id" is very general name for a form input.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce Yeah that might be a good idea. Thanks for the help!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of AJAX is to be able to communicate with the server *without* having to reload the page...

Submit the form with AJAX instead and then simply call your `FillCommentsTable` again.

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return deleteComment()">
  <input type="number" name="id">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>

function deleteComment() {
  var id = document.querySelector("input[name='id']");
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      FillCommentsTable();
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "API/delete_comment.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("id="+encodeURIComponent(id.value));
  return false;
}
```

**Edit:**
The above successfully sends the GET request retrieving the data. In addition to these changes I also added

```
  new_tbody.setAttribute("id","comments");
```

in the FillCommentsTable function. The mistake of omitting this caused the comments table body to lose its name on the first reload which then caused subsequent calls to FillCommentTable to have no effect since there is no tbody called "comments" ...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have two data call functions, one to GET data from DB and one to POST data to your DB.

```
function FillCommentsTable() {
  //Function Stuff
}

function AddNewComment() {
  //Function Stuff
}
```

You have a few options on how to process the data:

1. On POST of a new item, after you receive a status of 200, call your
       `FillCommentsTable` function.
2. If you have an array storing your comments on the client side, as
   you make your POST call and after you receive a status of OK,
   `array.push(newComment)`

You can also take advantage of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (Browser support, ECMA2015) to ensure sequencing. I will leave it at a resource link for now as its not exactly within scope of the OP.